# How does nosetests find tests to run?

Tags: python

I am trying to run all pyunit tests in a directory using nosetests.  The problem is that I have 4 tests in this directory and nosetests is only running one of them.  If I run the other three tests individually like:

```
nosetests -v thistestwillrunnow.py
```

then the tests will run.  But I thought just saying:

```
nosetests
```

would run all tests in the directory without having to run them one at a time.

How does nosetests find tests to run?

Comment: I figured it out.  Every test in the directory has to be named 'test*'.  So test1.py or testFirst.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"If it looks like a test, it’s a test" !**

This is extracted [from nose documentation](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/finding_tests.html).

Personnaly I store my tests files in `test` sub-directories right in my module's directories like this :

```
src/module1/test
src/module2/test
src/module2/sub_module/test
```

And it works very well :)